# Flutter - When to close streams when using dependency injection

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, stream, bloc

If I instantiate a BLoC in MyWidget, I'll usually use a `StatefulWidget` and close the stream in the `dispose` method like so:

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ...
  @override
  void initState() {
    // ...
    bloc = MyBloc()
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.stream.close();
    // ...
  }
 ...
}
```

However, when I inject a provided instance of MyBloc into MyWidget (maybe via MyWidget's constructor), I close the stream higher up the widget hierarchy since **MyWidget does not get a new instance of MyBloc with a new Stream when the user navigates away from and back to MyWidget**.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyBloc bloc;
  MyWidget(this.bloc) ... ;
  ..
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ...
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Not closing stream here anymore. Closing higher up because 
    // I don't get a fresh instance when user comes back here;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Does this cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem, as long that the widget that created your object correctly dispose it when removed from the widget tree.

In fact, descendants should **not** call `dispose` on their parameters.

Doing so is an anti-pattern, as a descendant don't have the ownership of their parameter and therefore should not do any modifications on it.